# What is the right way of including stylesheets and scripts in Angular5?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Code Concrete</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="btn-test">Click this!</button>

  <!--Latest Jquery Library-->
  <script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Custom JS-->
  <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap styles work with that format. But the html can't seem to load the jquery library. I checked the path and everything, and everything seems right to me. What am I doing wrong here? And what is the right way to include stylesheets and scripts in angular5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use your anguar cli json to add extenal scripts and stylesheets.

Comment: If you are using Angular cli then they should be mentioned in .angular-cli.json file at the "styles" and "scripts" property .

Answer (score 0):

> what is the right way to include stylesheets and scripts in angular5?

In angular(v5) right way to import these file to include it into the `.angular-cli.json` file under the `styles` and `scripts` array. like this -

```
        "styles": [
           "assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "assets/js/custom.js",
          "/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        ],
```

PS: In latest version of Angular (v6) `.angular-cli.json` file has been renamed with `angular.json` file

Answer (score 0):

You can add external scripts and styles to your project by adding paths of  your scripts and style sheets to angular-cli.json file.

```
{
  "scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
  "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
//
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
}
```

Comment: Where can I see angular-cli.json?

Comment: In your project directory root

Comment: If you created project by using angular-cli then angular-cli.json will be in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Angular-CLI and many other angular developers use Webpack to bundle everything together to a more efficient production application.

So it's very common to feed it in a way the configuration file can see it clearly.

If you use angular-cli up to Angular 5, it should be inside, `.angular-cli.json`

[image]

Now I believe in Angular 6 it's `angular.json` file

Comment: I edit angular.json file and put all my style and script paths. At first it didn't work. I tried restarting server via angular-cli with "ng serve". And voila! It works!   Thanks very much!